# Explain me the advantage to use Cronjob inside your code our outside your code?

Tags: cron, microservices

i have to do a reptitive task in nodeJS and i've seen there is existing package like this one.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

and the actual platform where i'm hosted propose inside cronjob.

https://www.netlify.com/docs/webhooks/

so my question is when it's more interessant to use the platform or a package.

thanks.

Comment: Why don't use AWS Lambda to schedule your cron directly from the console?

Answer (score 0):

From the URL posted i didn't see any method of setting up a cron job using webhooks. Unless you were thinking of setting up a webhook that listens for a post which is sent using a linux cron job or the like?

Regardless, the actual question about using a platform or a package. They have pros and cons, but based purely on your question I would go with the platform.

If you choose to use a package you will have to write the code to call the package (which you need to test, maintain and run). You need to ensure that the node process is always up and running, if it dies or exits that it is re-spawned, that if the operating system reboots the node process gets kicked off again. All these problems are can be easily solved (PM2 for instance) but the fact is you need to think of the problems and solve them yourself or the cron job might not run when you want it to.

When using the platform you know that it is well tested, that it will work as documented, and that it will be resilient to failure modes that you might not be aware of.